# R markdown - printing datatable from inside the function

Tags: r, r-markdown, dt

I have the followin markdown:

````
---
title: "My report"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(DT)

my_func <- function(x) {
  #DT::datatable(x)
  print(DT::datatable(x))
  nrow(x)
}
```

```{r}
x <- my_func(mtcars)
print(x)
```
````

I want to display a DT from inside the function, but this function performs some calculations that I'm interested in the output of. So far it doesn't display the table. How can I force markdown to generate a table without returning it?

Comment: Which calculation, add to question an example if they are secret.

Comment: it doesn't matter, let's say `nrow(x)`

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

````
---
title: "My report"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(DT)

my_func <- function(x) {
  res <- list(dt = DT::datatable(x), 
              nr = nrow(x))
  class(res) <- "myfun"
  invisible(res)
}
```

```{r}
x <- my_func(mtcars)
x$nr
```


```{r}
x$dt
```
````

Comment: Well, that's all workarounds, that make the code messy, I was hoping to find some alternative to `print` that would render datatable within my code chunk, and not creating a new one.